# How can I get two or more IF AND statements working together?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in Excel and i need to write an "if" statement based on Values (figures) in three different cells e.g **1.3**  | **4.4**  | **9.25** | to generate values like **Better**, **Good**, **Fair**, **Excellent** as below. Check [image]

I tried using many if as below and could not get anywhere in acheiving what i want

```
=IF((AND(D2=1.35,F2=9.25,D2=1.35,F2=7.75,D2=1.4,F2>=6,D2=1.45,F2=5.5), "Good", "Worse",
IF(AND(D2=1.5,F2=5.25,D2=1.5,F2=5.25,D2=1.55,F2=5.25,D2=1.55,F2=4.4))," OK","Excelent")
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thx

Comment: Is this supposed to be one or two formulas? Your parentheses are out of place in a couple spots. It is closest to being two completely independent statements, which would be =IF(AND(D2=1.35,F2=9.25,D2=1.35,F2=7.75,D2=1.4,F2>=6,D2=1.45,F2=5.5), "Good", "Worse")  and   =IF(AND(D2=1.5,F2=5.25,D2=1.5,F2=5.25,D2=1.55,F2=5.25,D2=1.55,F2=4.4)," OK","Excellent")

Comment: Aside from that, I believe you could accomplish your goal much better another way, but we need to know more about the parameters for each output. You are currently missing "better" altogether.

Comment: Agreed with @JacobEdmond. If you have defined thresholds, you could probably create a lookup table to determine statuses, rather than using these incredibly complicated IF statements.

Comment: can u explain the algorithm a little more in elaborate

Comment: F2 **cannot** be equal to 9.25 AND be equal to 7.75 AND be equal to 5.5. You need to pair up the D2 and F2 conditions with AND and string them together with OR. e.g. `=IF(OR(AND(D2=1.35,F2=9.25), AND(D2=1.35,F2=7.75), AND(D2=1.4,F2>=6), AND(D2=1.45,F2=5.5)), "Good", "Worse"`

Comment: What is the criteria that you are setting for better, fair, excellent or good?

Comment: With @Jeeped method I was able to achieve something. I then released I had to make a column for  each combination of statuses e.g "OK" with "Excellent" In one column, "Good" with "Worse" in another Column.. Etc as Jacob Edmond suggested. Is there a way I can put them all in one Column?

Comment: @aspan88 if D2=1.3,F2=9.25  "Better". if D2=1.4, F2=6.5  and if D2=1.45,F2=6.5 and if D2=1.55,F2=6.5 "Fair". If D2=1.45,F2=7.25 "Excellent". If D2=1.3,F2=7.75  "Good". If D2=1.3,E2=4.7 "Bad"  don't know if that will help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will work for you

```
=IF(AND(D6=1.3,E6=9.25),"Better",IF(AND(OR(D6=1.4,D6=1.45,D6=1.55),E6=6.5),"Fair",IF(AND(D6=1.45,E6=7.25),"Excellent",IF(AND(D6=1.3,E6=7.75),"Good","Bad"))))
```

Comment: The Formula works fine however am trying to deal with a situation when it says too many arguments? As am trying to add more if(AND(OR @aspan88

Comment: Please take a look at the formula below  `=IF(AND(D15=1.3,F15=9.25),"1",IF(AND(OR(D15=1.4,D15=1.45,D15=1.55),F15=5.75),"O2.5",IF(AND(OR(D15=1.3,D15=1.35),F15=8.25),"1 N GGNo",IF(AND(D15=1.35,F15=7.5),"1 or 1X",IF(AND(D15=1.35,E15=5,F15=6),"1",IF(AND(OR(D15=1.45,D15=1.4),F15=7.25,F15=6.75),"1",IF(AND(D15=1.3,F15=7.75),"1"," ")))))))`